# What's the safest way to switch and restore a post global?

Tags: posts, globals

I need to switch WordPress's post context, sort of like `switch_to_blog()` but for posts. What's the safest way to alter WordPress's global state and switch it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setup_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Access_all_post_data) to change and [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) to roll back to original.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks Rarst. I don't need to loop through any posts. Just get a single one via `get_post( $post_id )`. Is this still the way to go given that background? I'm not using `have_post()`, `the_post()` and the like, just `get_post()`. (Googlers, see also: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query)

Comment: @editor yep, same principle. The point of `setup_postdata()` is that it doesn't care about the Loop or more precisely it's one of small standalone cogs in it.